# Regex que me permita incluir saltos de línea

Tags: javascript, regex

Tengo la siguiente expresión regular para validar la cantidad de caracteres máxima aceptada en un input:

```
new RegExp(`^.{0,100}$`)
```

Funciona bien, excepto porque si el usuario da enter, la regex pasa a devolver `false`. ¿Cómo resolverlo para que acepte el rango de caracteres incluyendo saltos de línea y enters?

Answer (score 2):

Un punto `.` coincide con todos los caracteres menos los saltos de línea..

***EXCEPTO*** cuando se usa el modificador `s`, que coincide con absolutamente todos los caracteres.

```
var r = new RegExp('^.{0,100}$', 's');
```

O lo que es lo mismo:

```
var r = /^.{0,100}$/s;
```